# How can I find the only real and then the smallest root of a 4th-order polynomial?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I just want to solve the below polynomial for real roots only, where I have mentioned the conditions on all variables, a,d,m,L.

```
FFF4[x_, a_, d_, m_, L_] =  Refine[a x^4 +   4 a (1 - d) x^3 + (1 + a m^2 L^2 + 10 a + 5 a d +  a d^2) x^2 + (6 a - d - 3 a d + a d m^2 L^2) x -  m^2  L^2, {Element[L, Reals], Element[m, Reals], Element[a, Reals],Element[d, Integers], L > 0, a > 0, m > o, d > 0}]
```

Next I tried to solve this, and got the four roots

```
Sol = Solve[FFF4[x, a, d, m, L] == 0, x];
```

However, now I need to find the smallest root. We have choice to fix d=4 and a=0.1. How can I find the smallest root here?

And if I modify my code like

```
Sol = Solve[FFF4[x, a, d, m, L] == 0, x, Reals];
```

Mathematica takes so much time and does not give any input.

Answer (score 7):

If there's a real root, then `Root[polyfunc, 1]` represents the smallest one and takes only a few milliseconds to compute:

```
Root[fff4[#, a, d, m, L] &, 1]
(*
  Root[-L^2 m^2 + (6 a - d - 3 a d + a d L^2 m^2) #1 + (1 + 10 a + 
        5 a d + a d^2 + a L^2 m^2) #1^2 + (4 a - 4 a d) #1^3 + 
     a #1^4 &, 1]
*)
```

To get a numeric value:

```
Root[fff4[#, a, d, m, L] &, 1] /.
 {d -> 4, a -> 1/10, L -> 1, m -> 2} // N
(*  -0.579658  *)
```

If you want algebraic formulas representing the least root, then expect a complicated dependence on the parameters that may take a long time to compute.  The `Root[]` object can be manipulated symbolically and numerically and is more efficient.  If you have a question about how to use it in a specific way, post another question to the site.

Example:

```
r1 = Root[fff4[#, a, d, m, L] &, 1] /. {d -> 4, a -> 0.1};
Plot3D[r1, {m, 0, 4}, {L, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanyou Very much #Michael E2. But if i want to save this data in a table form, because later i want to guess what are the lowest possible values of m and L. For the smallest real root?

Comment: @ImmySalam Replace `Plot3D` by `Table` in the example.  Look up `Table` for to adjust it. To find the smallest root, look up `FindMinimum`, but it looks like that wouldn’t exist (would approach the `Limit` as `m` and `L approach infinity).

Comment: This seems to give the correct minimum: `r1 = Root[fff4[#, a, d, m, L] &, 1] /. {d -> 4, a -> 1/10};
MinValue[{r1, m > 0 && L > 0}, {m, L}]`

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

FFF4[x_, a_, d_, m_, L_] = 
  a x^4 + 
   4 a (1 - d) x^3 + (1 + a m^2 L^2 + 10 a + 5 a d + a d^2) x^2 + (6 a - d - 
      3 a d + a d m^2 L^2) x - m^2 L^2;
```

Put the constraints in the [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
sol = Solve[{FFF4[x, a, d, m, L] == 0, 
  L > 0, a > 0, m > 0, d > 0}, x, Reals];

Length@sol

(* 4 *)

(sol2 = Select[sol /. {d -> 4, a -> 1/10}, FreeQ[#, Undefined] &]) // Grid
```

[image]

To get numeric values you must also specify `L` and `m`

```
(sol3 = Select[sol /. {d -> 4, a -> 1/10, L -> 1, m -> 2}, 
   FreeQ[#, Undefined] &])
```

[image]

The smallest root is the first one

```
sol3[[1]] // N

(* {x -> -0.579658} *)

Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[x /. sol2],
  {m, 0, 5}, {L, 0, 5},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.8],
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
     {m, L, x}),
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 Graphics3D[
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{m, L, x} /. {L -> 1, m -> 2} /. sol3]}]]
```

[image]